# How did Hagrid retrieve baby Harry when the home was under Fidelius Charm?

Tags: harry-potter

After Harry's parents died, Dumbledore sent Hagrid to retrieve baby Harry from the Potter Cottage. But, the Potter Cottage was under Fidelius Charm at that time.

How was Hagrid able to locate the Potter Cottage and retrieve the baby Harry?

Comment: Was Dumbledore Secret Keeper? Maybe he put Hagrid in the loop when he sent him to retrieve Harry. I don't remember if that implies going to the house first.

Comment: @Jenayah No, Dumbledore wasn't Secret Keeper. Pettigrew was.

Comment: Ah, yes, but I thought you could have multiple Secret Keepers - isn't that the case for Grimmauld Square? (but the again I was probably thinking of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83853/98028) and its answers)